# how to create a MariaDB database in google cloud platform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, mariadb

I did not get it right as it does to create a MariaDB database
Most tutorials show how to create MySQL, but I'm still in doubt.

Comment: Show us what happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want you can one click deploy:

https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/google/mariadb10?filter=solution-type:container&id=1082de93-67cf-464e-8cec-c5137645640a

Alternatively, you can write your own Dockerfile which pulls in any config files you want, in order to set up the DB, and push to a container registry.

Comment: Thanks, You helped me a lot with it